# How to list only new cookies in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, security, cookies, whitelist

All Firefox version can be configured to delete cookies on exit, but "white list" certain cookies, preventing those from being deleted on exit.  I happen to be using the current version of Firefox, 57, on Windows 7.

Some web sites implement extra security process, such as a phone call, email or SMS text message if the site doesn't find a cookie from a former visit.

In order to avoid the extra security process, it would be beneficial to discover what cookies were newly added after successfully completing the extra security process so that the cookies resulting from that process can be preserved (through the white list) instead of getting discarded on exit.

Although it's possible to examine the list before and after the extra security process and try to spot the differences, this manual process can be tedious and error prone.  Often the domain for the security site that saves the cookie is not the main domain of the site you're visiting, which makes manual detection of the additional cookie more difficult.

**Is there a process to list only the cookies that have changed in the last specified time period or a "listener" that will show what cookies are added in real time?**

Comment: Any answers will depend on 1/ What operating system you are using and 2/ What version of Firefox you are using. Please [edit] your question to include this essential information.

Comment: I don't see what the issue is. In the cookie white list you add websites, so any cookies generated from that visit should be OK (select "Allow"). I doubt any secure site would use third party url cookies, since many people block these as a matter of course.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I have added the Firefox and OS specifics.

Comment: @user3169, the issue is how to discover what cookies are created without a lot of manual effort.  How the white list functions is not a problem and isn't part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

A Firefox extension or an external app will be necessary for that sort of task. One such Windows utility that can display info (including time of creation) for all persistent (on-disk) FF cookies is MZCookiesView from
NirSoft: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mzcv.html

Comment: This might be as close as I get.  The command line feature means that I could do a "before and after" snapshot and write my own code to find the difference.  Upvoted, but want to leave it open in case someone else has an option that doesn't require me to do the snapshot compares.

Comment: If you find an extension, it might be a good answer to https://redd.it/cct0jt